# how to call two different .ctp file in one function in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp

I have 2 view files `index.ctp` and `indexMobile.ctp`.
i have to use one single controller `logincontroller.php` and a single function for both ctp file.

Comment: I would strongly recommend you to use [Elements](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#elements) in both your files.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to render a specific view use $this->render in your controller

```
$this->render('your_view_file');
```

[see Rendering a specific view](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#rendering-a-specific-view)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my example:

```
// Changing the "layout" (app/View/Layouts") if you want.
// Change this if you want a different layout for this view.
$this->layout='pdf';

// Folder where is the .ctp View file. 
// This is also optional, if your view is in some other folder.
$this->viewPath = 'Pdf';

// Call the "{$view}.ctp" in "Pdf" folder (app/View/Pdf/{$view}.ctp).
// Use this for choosing the right View.
$this->render($view);
```

Comment: Although (based on the naming in the original question), a different layout is probably desired, your answer is doing far more then asked by the OP. Also your examples do not really match the intent (pdf?). Please improve your answer. Explain the basics first and (optionally) explain advantages of switching layouts etc.